# Derivative of a function that's evaluated at a point

Tags: calculus, notation, partial-derivative

If $f(x,y)$ is differentiable then what would $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[f(x,y)|_{x=a}\right]$$ evaluate to? Would it be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)|_{x=a}$? Or $0$ since $x$ is being substituted $a$ prior to the derivative? Or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: If you evaluate $f$ at $x=a$ *before* deriving, the derivative will be zero as it's constant in the $x$-direction.

I suspect what is meant here is to evaluate the derivative at $x = a$.

Comment: @RubenduBurck is hard to argue with :-), but I suspect it is bad notation, should have been $$\left. \frac{\partial [f(x,y)]}{\partial x} \right|_{x=a} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [f(x,y)] |_{x=a}$$

Comment: @RubenduBurck *derive* means “arrive at”; *differentiate* means “take the derivative of”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[f(x,y)\vert_{x=a}\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(a,y)]=0$$ since the expression $f(a,y)$ no longer contains $x$ and is thus constant in that respect.
2. $$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)\right]_{x=a}=[f_x(x,y)]_{x=a}=f_x(a,y)$$ where $f_x$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to $x$. The end result can be zero but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the expression as you have it is zero because you are taking derivative of a function which is not dependent on $x$ with respect to $x$